# How to set range of separate cells in DataSeriesValues PHPExcel RadarChart

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpoffice

I can't make radar chart with PHPExcel. I need to add to DataSeriesValues range of separate cells

```
$xAxisTickValues = [
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$5', NULL, 1),
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$10', NULL, 1),
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$14', NULL, 1),
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$17', NULL, 1),
]; //This works fine

$xAxisTickValues = [
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$5:$B$10', NULL, 1),
];//This works too
```

I need something like this:

```
    $xAxisTickValues = [
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$5;'.$sn.'!$A$15', NULL, 1),
    ]; //but this won't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it myself; but have you tried using a `,` separator for the ranges rather than a `;`? PHPExcel expects US/UK "syntax", and the separator for cell ranges in US/UK is the `,`

```
$xAxisTickValues = [
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sn.'!$B$5,'.$sn.'!$A$15', NULL, 1),
];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i've tried different separators, and this did not help.

Comment: Im dealing with the same thing, and this did not work for me.PLEASE can you have a look at my question @Mark Barker -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083470/php-excel-cant-render-proper-xaxis-range-in-charts